# I can't build ionic react app on IOS simulator

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor, ionic-react

I'm trying to build an Ionic React project. I’m successfully compiling the project on the IOS simulator but It crashes when It opens. Error showing is

```
⚡️ ERROR: Unable to load public/index.html
⚡️ This file is the root of your web app and must exist before
⚡️ Capacitor can run. Ensure you’ve run capacitor copy at least
⚡️ or, if embedding, that this directory exists as a resource directory.
```

I have posted on ionic forum as well, [Discussion Here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/i-cant-build-ionic-react-app-on-ios-simulator/209101)

Answer (score 2):

That means the app is not able to find the index.html file in the public folder.

If you run `npx cap open ios` it should open your Capacitor project in Xcode. There you should see a blue folder called public with the index.html on it.

If you don't see it, then first run `npm run build` and then `npx cap copy`.

If you still don't see it, check that the value of `webDir` in `capacitor.config.json` matches the folder to where react is building your app.